# Proving $f(x) = -x+2$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that$$
\int_2^x e^{-t} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = e^{-x} - e^{-2} - e^{-x} f(x).
$$
How can I prove that $f(x)=-x+2$?

Comment: I didn't try it, but my first attempt would be to take the derivative of each side with respect to $x$.

Comment: So ( \int_2^x e^{-t} f(t) \ )' = \e^(-x) f(x) \ ?

Comment: You should put dollar signs around the MathJax so it is readable.  I think the left side needs a $\frac d{dx}$ to make it true (update:  I missed the prime).  Then it is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The point of this exercise is to recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   differentiate both sides, then by the [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) and the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule):

$$\require{cancel}
\cancel{e^{-x} f(x)} = -e^{-x} + \cancel{e^{-x} f(x)} - e^{-x}f'(x) \quad\iff\quad f'(x) = -1
$$

Therefore $\,f(x)=-x+C\,$ where the constant $\,C\,$ can be determined by setting $\,x=2\,$ into the original relation.

Comment: One needs to show that $f$ is differentiable, which is easy. But one should think about that in advance.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Right, and that's a good point. A full proof would need to state that $\,f\,$ is indeed differentiable since $\,f(x) = e^x \cdot \left(e^{-x}-e^{-2}- \int_2^x e^{-t}f(t) \text{d}t\right)\,$ where the RHS is differentiable.